# Array gets overwritten for no apparent reason

Tags: java, android

## Problem

---

I have written a loop in which I fill an array with Sum objects. Everything works fine, but as soon as the loop gets to the next iteration it overwrites the first index of the array.

## What have I tried

---

I tried to see if maybe my problem resides in a different piece of code (such as my Sum class). But could not find anything that would disturb the loop.
I tried to find other variables with the same name (even in other methods, since I was desperate) and see if I maybe changed my iterator somewhere else. I couldn't find anything related to that.
I tried looking around on the internet and SO to find something related to accidentally overwriting arrays but couldn't find anything either.

## Code

---

```
public Task(Object[] parameters)
{
    this.number_of_sums = Integer.parseInt((String)parameters[0]);
    this.variables_per_sum = Integer.parseInt((String)parameters[1]);
    this.sum_parameters = new Object[this.variables_per_sum];
    this.sums = new Sum[this.number_of_sums];
    int z = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.number_of_sums; i++)
    {
        int x = 0;
        for(int j = (2 + z); j < ((this.variables_per_sum + 2) + z); j++)
        {
            this.sum_parameters[x] = parameters[j];
            x++;
        }

        this.sums[i] = new Sum(this.sum_parameters);

        System.out.println("Index 0: "+sums[0]); //1st iteration: 1 + 1 //2nd iteration: 2 - 1
        System.out.println("Index 1: "+sums[1]); //1st iteration: null //2nd iteration: 2 - 1

        z += this.variables_per_sum;
    }
}
```

## Expectations

---

I'm expecting the output of 1 + 1 and 2 - 1. I am however getting the following: 2 - 1 and 2 - 1 when I'm done.

If anyone spots anything I'm doing wrong or would like to see more information or code on my side please say so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is hard to follow.  Best bet?  Step through in a debugger and see exactly what's going on.  You'll figure it out faster than getting an answer here.

Comment: All your `Sum`s are sharing the same array (`this.sum_parameters`). You should make a new one per each main iteration.

Comment: @Esailija what do you mean by this? I want every `Sum` to be stored in the same array, just at a different index (ofcourse). How would I go about preventing this?
@duffymo Thanks, I understand that the code is hard to follow (though it works so as it's supposed to, except for storing the results in the array). My only question is why the `Sum` gets saved in every index in stead of just one index.

Comment: @Bono they all reference sum_parameters internally and don't let go of it after construction, so when it is changed for the second object, it also changes for the first.

Comment: @Bono For indices, you always have `x = 0`, and `x++`. I don't know what to replace that with except to use a different array for storage. And how would a Sum object even know what indices to use in the shared array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume the `Sum` class doesn't store its sum, but instead computes it from the array it was constructed with whenever it's needed.

It looks like all the `Sum` objects will share the same array -- you're passing the same reference every time you construct a `Sum`. Furthermore, every time you loop over `j` you overwrite the contents of that array.

So when everything is done, all the sums are the same.

You should be able to get around this by giving each `Sum` a different `sum_parameters`:

```
public Task(Object[] parameters)
{
    this.number_of_sums = Integer.parseInt((String)parameters[0]);
    this.variables_per_sum = Integer.parseInt((String)parameters[1]);
    this.sums = new Sum[this.number_of_sums];
    int z = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.number_of_sums; i++)
    {
        Object[] sum_parameters = new Object[this.variables_per_sum];
        int x = 0;
        for(int j = (2 + z); j < ((this.variables_per_sum + 2) + z); j++)
        {
            sum_parameters[x] = parameters[j];
            x++;
        }

        this.sums[i] = new Sum(sum_parameters);

        System.out.println("Index 0: "+sums[0]); //1st iteration: 1 + 1 //2nd iteration: 2 - 1
        System.out.println("Index 1: "+sums[1]); //1st iteration: null //2nd iteration: 2 - 1

        z += this.variables_per_sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, chose to accept this as the answer since it's a little more detailed and has a code example.

Answer (score 1):

Each one of your `Sum` objects is constructed with `this.sum_parameters` as a parameter:

```
this.sums[i] = new Sum(this.sum_parameters);
```

When `sum_parameters` is modified in each iteration of the outer loop, it changes internally in the objects constructed around *references to it*.

You should make an internal copy of `sum_parameters` in each `Sum` object.

Comment: Thank you very much, clear explanation made me get it. It makes a lot of sense now I think about it.